# image classification using SVM and BOW?

Tags: c++, opencv

i am not too experienced with openCV. I have some images and i want to check whether they contain a sign which i am looking for or not. So, i want to use the SVM technique for which i have some code. I have understood most the parts of the code but i don't know how can i implement this code. The code has three functions i.e. `createTrainDataUsingBow()` second is
`int trainSVM` and `int svmPredict`.

**Problem:** I know that first i have to train the SVM and then use the predict(). But, i don't understand the arguments to be passed during their call. I mean, if i create a `main()` then with what parameters i should call the `int trainSVM`.

The whole code is given below:

**1.** Code for createTrainDataUsingBow()

```
void createTrainDataUsingBow(std::vector<char*> files, cv::Mat& train, cv::Mat&        response, int label)
{
    cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher> matcher =    cv::DescriptorMatcher::create("FlannBased");
    cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> extractor = new cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor();
    cv::BOWImgDescriptorExtractor dextract( extractor, matcher );
    cv::SurfFeatureDetector detector(500);

    // cluster count
    int cluster = 100;

    // create the object for the vocabulary.
    cv::BOWKMeansTrainer bow( cluster,cv::TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, FLT_EPSILON), 1, cv::KMEANS_PP_CENTERS );

    // get SURF descriptors and add to BOW each input files
    std::vector<char*>::const_iterator file;
    for( file = files.begin(); file != files.end(); file++)
    {
        cv::Mat img = cv::imread( *file, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
        std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints = detector.detect( img, keypoints);
        cv::Mat descriptors;
        extractor->compute( img, keypoints, descriptors);
        if ( !descriptors.empty() ) bow.add( descriptors );
    }

    // Create the vocabulary with KMeans.
    cv::Mat vocabulary;
    vocabulary = bow.cluster();

    for( file = files.begin(); file != files.end(); file++)
    {
        // set training data using BOWImgDescriptorExtractor
        dextract.setVocabulary( vocabulary );
        std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
        cv::Mat img = cv::imread( *file, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
        detector.detect( img, keypoints);
        cv::Mat desc;
        dextract.compute( img, keypoints, desc );
        if ( !desc.empty() )
        {
            train.push_back( desc );            // update training data
            response.push_back( label );        // update response data
        }
    }
}
```

**2.** Code for trainSVM()

```
int trainSVM((std::vector<char*> positive, std::vector<char*> negative)
{
    // create training data
    cv::Mat train;
    cv::Mat response;
    createTrainDataUsingBow(positive, train, response, 1.0);
    createTrainDataUsingBow(negative, train, response, -1.0);

    // svm parameters
    CvTermCriteria criteria = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 1000, FLT_EPSILON);
    CvSVMParams svm_param = CvSVMParams( CvSVM::C_SVC, CvSVM::RBF, 10.0, 8.0, 1.0, 10.0,     0.5, 0.1, NULL, criteria);

    // train svm
    cv::SVM svm;
    svm.train(train, response, cv::Mat(), cv::Mat(), svm_param);
    svm.save("svm-classifier.xml");

    return 0;
}
```

**3.** Code for svmPredict()

```
int svmPredict(const char* classifier, const char* vocaname, const char* query, const char* method)
{
    // load image
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(query, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    // load svm
    cv::SVM svm;
    svm.load(classifier);

    // declare BOWImgDescriptorExtractor
    cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorMatcher> matcher =     cv::DescriptorMatcher::create("FlannBased");
    cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> extractor = new cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor();
    cv::BOWImgDescriptorExtractor dextract( extractor, matcher );

    // load vocabulary data
    cv::Mat vocabulary;
    cv::FileStorage fs( vocaname, cv::FileStorage::READ);
    fs["vocabulary data"] >> vocabulary;
    fs.release();
    if( vocabulary.empty()  ) return 1;

    // Set the vocabulary
    dextract.setVocabulary( vocabulary );
    std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
    detector.detect( img, keypoints);
    cv::Mat desc_bow;
    dextract.compute( img, keypoints, desc_bow );
    if( desc_bow.empty() )  return 1;

    // svm predict
    float predict = svm.predict(centroids, true);

    std::cout << predict << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what parameters i should call the int trainSVM.

trainSVM() takes two char* vectors which are lists of names of image files for the positive and negative samples respectively.
It would probably best to make a file containing a list of positive image filenames, and the same for negatives, and to read those in.

BTW, this line has a syntax error:

```
int trainSVM((std::vector<char*> positive, std::vector<char*> negative)
```

A bigger concern is how are you going to normailize the data, and how are you going to do cross validation to get the proper values for svm_params?

Also, since `svmPredict()` reloads everything for every test case, it will be very inefficient.

You would be probably be better off using the [libsvm](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) command line tools until you know whether it is going to work. It would be trivial to dump the mats output from `createTrainDataUsingBow()`  data in libsvm format.

Comment: thanks, i understood the code and its arguments but i am still facing problem in creating a svmPredict(). For that, i am going to post a new question.